# How to set default value in drop down using ng-options?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

Am using a drop down box in my form which lists items.

this is html code :

```
<tr>
  <td><label>items</label></td>
  <td>
    <select ng-model="addItems.item" ng-options="item.name for item in itemList" ng-init="getItemsList()">                       
    </select>
  </td>
</tr>
```

this is my controller:

```
$scope.getItemsList = function() {
    $http({
        method : "GET" ,
        url : "/items/allitems"
    }).success(function(data) {
        $scope.itemList = data;                              
        $scope.additems.item = $scope.itemList[0].id;
    });
};
```

Problem is :Am getting item's list from controller and binded those through ng-model. But i list item's name in drop down and if i select any then particular item's id will be sent to database for storing.

If i run this code i got the below result in browser :

```
<option value="?" selected="selected"></option>
<option value="0">pen</option>
<option value="1">notebook</option>
<option value="2">marker</option>
```

Can anyone please tel me whether i did any mistake and give me a tips to have 1st value as default one instead of empty selection

Comment: Use "item.id as item.name for item in itemList". Without the first part it will store the name in additems.item, and it will not work. Conversely you could just do $scope.additems.item = $scope.itemList[i].name;

Comment: no it didnt work zack.still it shows the empty value as default :(

Answer (score 0):

There might be one tip for ng-init label and I met this similar issue before.
You can use below html codes:

```
<tr>
  <td><label>items</label></td>
  <td ng-init="getItemsList()">
    <select ng-model="addItems.item" ng-options="item.name for item in itemList">                       
    </select>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: i tried this but i dont know why there is an empty space in drop down while i use ng-model.its not getting selected.

Comment: You can try this: <select ng-model="addItems.item" ng-options="item.name for item in itemList"><option value="">default value</option>                      
</select>

Answer (score 0):

change your ng-options to

```
ng-options="item.id as item.name for item in itemList"
```

and your code should then work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use dropdown option id or name assigning index to the model on dropdown init
as given below

```html
<tr>
  <td><label>items</label></td>
  <td>
    <select ng-model="addItems.item" ng-options="item.id as item.name for item in itemList" ng-init="addItems.item=itemList[0].id">                       
    </select>
  </td>
</tr>
```